# How to get ID3 tag of URL music

Tags: android

I want to get the ID3 tag of URL music file.
I try below code:

```
Uri mp3 = Uri.parse(URL);
MediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
mmr.setDataSource(this, mp3);
```

I want to get the embedded picture of the mp3 file and show it in ImageView.
How can I do to arrive it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
MediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
mmr.setDataSource(URL);
byte[] b = mmr.getEmbeddedPicture();
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(b, 0, b.length);
```

Try it.